# How to avoid this busy loop?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to optimize a scan operation in redis. In order to do so, I spawn one thread per node and perform the scan operation on each node.

This is the code

```
    private Map<String, String> clusterScan(JedisCluster jc)
    {
        Map<String, String> valuesMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(jc.getClusterNodes().size());

        for (Map.Entry<String, JedisPool> nodeEntry : jc.getClusterNodes().entrySet())
        {
            service.submit(build(nodeEntry.getKey(), nodeEntry.getValue(), valuesMap));
        }
        service.shutdown();
        while(!service.isTerminated()) {}
        return valuesMap();
    }

    private Runnable build(String nodeName, JedisPool nodePool, Map<String, String> valuesMap) 
    {
        // Runnable to update the Map per node
    }
```

There is a busy loop waiting that the service is terminated. How may I avoid it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: @JBNizet should you write an answer I will gladly mark it as accepted, because it is exactly what I need. Thanks